# Custom text editor

Tags: javascript, angular, text-editor, rich-text-editor

we have a web application, frontend written in Angular 7.

we have a textarea in the app. We want to segregate textarea information into multiple parts based on a delimiter.

semicolon followed by a new line is the delimiter. So If I paste/write following information in the textarea

```
test1 test2 test3;

test1 test test3 test4
test1 test test3 test4
```

then it should display like following

[image]

So that user easily understands that he is sending two objects to the backend.

I hope it won't possible in textarea but are there any options available for this kind of requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: i don't write Angular, but i JavaScript i would do this.
1. on blur, or change, get all user input , detect word break
2. Replace the word break with an hr Tag
3. replace the current value into the DOM.

Comment: Hi Neon, then text editor becomes html editor right ?

Comment: i cant think of a better approach, because if you want the user to see it, you need to do some parsing in the DOM, if it was to be handled by the backend , it would have been way easier.. again i dont write angular, just a suggestion.

Comment: what is your use-case here.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this to send a valid object to the backend

```js
const txtArea = `test1 test2 test3;

test1 test test3 test4
test1 test test3 test4`

const obj =
  Object.entries(txtArea.split(';'))
  .reduce((acc, [x, y]) => ({ ...acc,
    [x]: y
  }), {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I want to visualize multiple objects in the UI to the user before sending it to backend

Comment: but still you want a valid object format, which this answer provides? You can easily use for visualising the data on the frontend